# How to keep IDREF link when unmarshalling an object with JAXB for cloning?

Tags: xsd, jaxb, clone, unmarshalling, deep-copy

I defined objects with XSD model and I used Jaxb to create corresponding classes, to be able to load XML files on instance of classes and to generate XML files from instance of classes.

My elements defined on the XSD model are complex with several hierarchical level, using list, ID and IDREF.

One command of my program is to duplicate elements.

I can't use the clone method cause classes of element are generated by JAXB.
So i have tried to do deep copy with BeanUtils.cloneBean, next with SerializationUtils.clone from Apache but both methods don't work correctly with all my objects because of their complexity.

I found a solution that work, using JAXB to create a clone unmarshalling my element :

```
public ObjectXML duplicate(ObjectXML objectXML) throws JAXBException {

  JAXBContext sourceJaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(objectXML.getClass());
  JAXBContext targetJaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(objectXML.getClass());

  Unmarshaller unmarshaller = targetJaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

  ObjectXML objectCopy = (ObjectXML) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new JAXBSource(sourceJaxbContext, objectXML));

  return objectCopy;
}
```

ObjectXML is my parent class from all elements generated by JAXB. All elements inherit directly or indirectly from this class.

This method work fine except with IDREF attributes that link to another object : JAXB don't know the element that have the corresponding ID when I unmarshall an individual object, so it assign null to the attribute.

Have someone a solution to keep IDREF on the copy when linked object are not supplied to the unmarshal of JAXB?

Thank you for advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few hints.

- Try the [copyable](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Copyable+plugin) plugin from [JAXB2-Basics](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics). This plugin generates deep reflection-free copying methods which handle JAXB structures very well, and you can also specify your own copying strategy. **Disclaimer:** I'm the author.
- Implement and register your own `IDResolver`, see [this blog post](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2005/08/pluggable_ididr.html). This would allow you to plug your own ID resolution strategy.

Comment: Implementing and using IDResolver is exactly what I need. It works perfectly. Thank you very much.